# Equivariant flat U(1) bundle on a torus

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles, connections, equivariant-cohomology

I am trying to understand equivariant flat $U(1)$ bundles on a torus, $(S^1)^N$. By equivariant, I mean equivariance with respect to the natural action of $(U(1))^N$ on $(S^1)^N$.

$G$-equivariant bundles should satisfy the equivariant Bianchi identity,
\begin{equation}
\nabla\mu(X)=\iota(X_M)F,
\end{equation}
as given in page 211 of Berline, Getzler and Vergne's `Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators' (BGV). Here, $\mu$ is the moment, $X$ is an element of the Lie algebra of $G$ (which is $(U(1))^N$ in my case), $X_M$ is its corresponding Killing vector field on the base space $M$ of the bundle (which is $(S^1)^N$ in my case), and $F$ is the curvature of the bundle.

Since I am interested in a $U(1)$ bundle, I believe the above identity should reduce to 
\begin{equation}
d\mu(X)=\iota(X_M)F
\end{equation}
(since $\nabla=d+[A,]$, where $A$ is the connection, and then since $U(1)$ has vanishing commutators, $\nabla=d$). Then, assuming that the bundle is flat reduces the identity to
\begin{equation}
d\mu(X)=0.
\end{equation}
In other words, it seems to me that the $\mu$, the moment, should be a constant. My question is, how do I determine this constant?

The following is my attempt at a solution. The formula for the moment, $\mu$ given in BGV is 
\begin{equation}
\mu(X)=\mathcal{L}(X_M)-[\iota(X_M),\nabla],
\end{equation}
where in my case $M=(S^1)^N$.

As mentioned above, $\nabla$ reduces to $d$, so we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\mu(X)&=\mathcal{L}(X_{(S^1)^N})-[\iota(X_{(S^1)^N}),d]\\
%&=2\mathcal{L}(X_{(S^1)^N})
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Then, since $\mu(X)=\sum_a^N\mu^aX^a$, I think we should have 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\mu^a&=\mathcal{L}(e^a_{(S^1)^N})-[\iota(e^a_{(S^1)^N}),d],
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $e^a_{(S^1)^N}$ are the generators of the $(U(1))^N$ action on ${(S^1)^N}$. I can't go beyond this, and am slightly confused since $\mu^a$ seems to be an operator in the expression above.

I believe that the constants given by $\mu^a$ should be proportional to the charges $Q^a$ of the  $(U(1))^N$ action on ${(S^1)^N}$. Any help would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**-
I have found a solution in equation (3.27) of `Equivariant Cohomology and Localization of Path Integrals' by Szabo. There, the moment map for a $G$-equivariant $U(1)$ bundle is given as
\begin{equation}
\mu(X)=\mathcal{L}(X_M)-[\iota,\nabla]=\iota(X_M)A=X^{\mu}A_{\mu},
\end{equation}
where $A$ is the $G$-invariant connection on the bundle, i.e., $F=dA$. For a $(U(1))^N$-equivariant flat $U(1)$ bundle, $X^{\mu}A_{\mu}$ is a constant as follows. $A_{\mu}$ is a constant since $F=dA=0$. The Killing vector field $X^{\mu}$ is constant, since the bundle is on $(S^1)^N$, and the Killing vector fields should just be proportional to the charges $Q^a_\mu$ of the $(U(1))^N$ action on $(S^1)^N$. However, I do not know how to show that 
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}(X_M)-[\iota,\nabla]=\iota(X_M)A
\end{equation}

Help with this computation together with corrections of any mistakes I've made above would be much appreciated, and will be accepted as the answer to this question.